# Background music in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

When playing a wave file in c++, the program no longer executes anything else. Normally you would have to wait for the track to finish then the program would continue, but I'm playing a looping track and I need it to play while the program executes. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

```
PlaySound("sleep_away.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP);

cout << "x1" << endl;
cin >> x1;

cout << "y1" << endl;
cin >> y1;

cout << "x2" << endl;
cin >> x2;

cout << "y2" << endl;
cin >> y2;

double f = slope (x1,y1,x2,y2);

cout << "y = " << m << "x + " << yi << endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SND_ASYNC   The sound is played asynchronously and PlaySound returns immediately
            after beginning the sound. To terminate an asynchronously played
            waveform sound, call PlaySound with pszSound set to NULL.
```

So:

```
PlaySound("sleep_away.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC);
```

Comment: I was looking at the audio documentation earlier today and completely over looked it, but it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin Lindley wrote, there is SND_ASYNC option in API, I didn't think about it. Alternatively you can have fun with threads.

**OR**

If you want to continue playing music while executing other code you need to start music playing code in different thread. You can accomplish it using `C++11` threads.

**Example code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void play_music() {
  PlaySound("sleep_away.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::thread t(play_music);

  // other code

  t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I chose Benjamin's option, but I will definitely keep this in mind for future reference. Thanks!